# Deep rails nested attributes on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form, the form has 'fields_for :addresses' and renders partial 'address_fields' in that 'fields_for :addresses', in that partial 'address_fields' there is 'fields_for :sub_address', when the browser is first loaded, the 'fields_for :sub_address' in the partial 'address_fields' appears, but when the 'Add Addresses' button is pressed the "fields_for :sub_address" element does not appear. So basically I have a nested form inside the nested form 'addresses', but it doesn't render when I click on 'Add Address'.

This is my 'Add Address' javascript code:

```
    class AddFields {
    constructor() {
        this.links = document.querySelectorAll('.add_fields');
        this.iterateLinks();
    }

    iterateLinks() {
        if (this.links.length === 0) return
        this.links.forEach(link => {
            link.addEventListener('click', e => {
                this.handleClick(link, e)
            });
        });
    }

    handleClick(link, e) {
        if (!link || !e) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        let time = new Date().getTime();
        let linkId = link.dataset.id;
        let regexp = linkId ? new RegExp(linkId, 'g') : null
        let newFields = regexp ? link.dataset.fields.replace(regexp, time) : null
        
        newFields ? link.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', newFields) :   null
        }

    }

    window.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => new AddFields());
```

here is my views:

`new.html.erb`

<%= form_with model: @data, url: address_path(token: params[:token]) do |form| %>

````
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            //another html here
        </div>
    </div>

    <fieldset>
        <div class="card mt-2">
          
            <div class="card-body">
                <%= form.fields_for :address do |addr| %>
                    <%= render 'sub_address_fields', form: addr %>
                <% end %>
                <%= link_to_add_fields 'Add Address', form, :addr %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.submit :'Submit', name: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-primary mt-2' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```
````

partial view:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
<%= form.hidden_field :_destroy %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        //another html here
    </div>

    <%= form.fields_for :sub_address do |sub_addr| %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <div class="custom-file form-control">
                        <%= sub_addr.label :id_card, class: 'id-card-label', for: 'id-card-file' %>
                        <%= sub_addr.file_field :attachment_id_card, id: 'id-card-file' %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <div class="custom-file form-control">
                        <%= sub_addr.label :self_assessment, class: 'self-assessment-label', for: 'self-assessment-file' %>
                        <%= sub_addr.file_field :attachment_self_assess, id: 'self-assess-file' %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <div class="custom-file form-control">
                        <%= sub_addr.label 'SWAB', class: 'swab-label', for: 'swab-file' %>
                        <%= sub_addr.file_field :attachment_swab, id: 'swab-file' %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    

<div class="form-group">
    <%= link_to "Remove", '#', class: "remove_fields"%>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is the helper:

```
module Frontend::Data::DataHelper
def link_to_add_fields(name, form, association)
    new_object = form.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = form.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id)   do |builder|
        render(association.to_s.singularize + '_fields', form: builder)
    end

    link_to(name, '#', class: 'add_fields', data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub('\n', '')})
end
end
```

Is javascript not able to display the form generated from the 'render' function on rails?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your view too?

Comment: @spickermann I've added views and more

Comment: I would seriously consider using event delegation instead of binding the handlers directly to the elements since you're both adding them dynamically and using turbolinks. This code also creates a bunch of elements with duplicate ids which is invalid HTML and more importantly creates unreliable behavior as `getElementById` may return the last element in the DOM (`id: 'id-card-file'`).